# UnboundID: how to configure multiple TLS protocols for LDAP over SSL connection?

Tags: ssl, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

We use UnboundID (unfortunately the old version that should be upgraded soon).

I want to configure multiple TLS protocols for LDAP over SSL connection: TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2.

Unfortunately, `com.unboundid.util.ssl.SSLUtil#createSSLContext(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)` supports only a single value:

```
  public SSLSocketFactory createSSLSocketFactory(final String protocol)
         throws GeneralSecurityException
  {
    return createSSLContext(protocol).getSocketFactory();
  }
```

How to configure multiple TLS protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `"TLSV1.2"` it will use any protocol version from there back as far as the JDK supports. What you are doing is configuring the *highest* TLS protocol version to use.

Comment: How can I configure the lowest TLS protocol?
I want to ensure that SSLv3 is not used.
Is it enough we use JDK higher than 8u31 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u31-relnotes-2389094.html?

Should we configure any protocol in this case?

Comment: Yes, that JRE version is sufficient, as long as you don't do what's mentioned in your link to re-enable it, and you aren't adding other security providers that support it.

Answer (score 1):

Specific settings for unboundid-ldap-sdk are controlled by:

```
com.unboundid.util.SSLUtil.setDefaultSSLProtocol("TLSv1");
com.unboundid.util.SSLUtil.setEnabledSSLProtocols(Arrays.asList("TLSv1"));
```

As shown in [Documentation](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/util/ssl/SSLUtil.html#setEnabledSSLProtocols(java.util.Collection)).